# iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Key' : boto amazon s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am new to boto I was trying out the tutorial at this link

```
    http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html
```

However every time I try to retrieve an item an error occurs.
My code is follows:

```
conn=boto.connect_s3(KEY,PRIVATEKEY) 
bucket= conn.create_bucket(bucketname)
from boto.s3.Key import Key
k= Key(bucket,'key')
k.get_contents_to_file(filename)
```

I get the following error:

```
k.get_contents_to_file('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
k.get_contents_to_file('test')
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 1253, in get_contents_to_file
response_headers=response_headers)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.py", line 1149, in get_file
for bytes in self:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Key'
```

I copied the code almost only thing is my s3 keys are different.

Comment: Is `KEY<PRIVATEKEY` a typo?

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem but you should be looking at the docs here: http://docs.pythonboto.org/

Comment: @ blender Yes a typo. Ill edit that.

Comment: k= Key(bucket,'filename')
The 'filename' should be the filename in the s3 browser right?

Comment: If it is any help I am using Python 3 and boto 2.3.0.